# Android : TextView set dynamically with RIGHT_OF

Tags: android

I need to set TextView dynamically, I have a word, and I want to create as TextView as there are letter in the word. So I put the first TextView and then each TextView on the right of the last one created. This is my code :

```
letters = new TextView[Anagrame.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < Anagrame.length(); i++)
    {
        TextView letter = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        letter.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square);
        letter.setText(String.valueOf(Anagrame.charAt(i)));
        letter.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        letter.setId(i);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        if (i > 0)
        {
            Log.d("I ", Integer.toString(i));
            Log.d("ID", Integer.toString(letters[i - 1].getId()));
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, letters[i - 1].getId());
        }
        letter.setLayoutParams(params);
        letters[i] = letter;
        anagrameLayout.addView(letter);

    }
```

Everything is fine except one thing the last TextView is not on the Right Position explanation :

The last TextView is on the same place than the first TextView, but when I checked in loop everything look fine, when I check log, the counter "i" and the id is good so I don't see the reason why the last one is not on the right of previous one but on the same place of the first one.

So if anyone have an idea, thanks in advance.

Comment: You better use `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"` which will automatically put newly created `textView` to the right of previous one.

Comment: Okay I m going to try this, I wanted RelativeLayout because following the numbers of letter I wanted to put on the right or below. Thanks